# How can I retrieve the query key for Bing Maps API for Enterprise in an Azure Resource Group Template?

Tags: json, azure-devops, bing-maps, azure-resource-manager

I am working on an ARM template that deploys an entire infrastructure from scratch:

1. The resource group
2. App Service plans
3. Application Insights
4. an so forth...

At some point I get to the part where I write the scripts for deploying my App Service (*for hosting and deploying my web app later on*) to my resource group. Prior to that I have my BingMaps API deployed in the same script.

I am stuck at the part where I am setting the Application Settings for my web app:

```
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "properties": {
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "SomeKey",
              "value": "SomeValue"
            }, //rest of the code omitted
```

I would like to know how could I retrieve my **BING MAPS query key** within an ARM template?

I have tried, and have a feeling that this might be close to it, something like:

```
"value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.BingMaps/mapApis', variables('bingMapsName')), '2016-08-18').queryKey]"
```

Anybody who has done this before? Many thanks in advance! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access query key in your ARM template for your web app setting, I would suggest you to use something like below:

```
{
    "name": "appsettings",
    "type": "config",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
    ],
    "tags": {
        "displayName": "WebAppSettings"
    },
    "properties": {
        "key1": "[parameter('AppSetting_Key1_Value')]",
        "key2": "value2"
    }
}
```

and then in your template.Parmeter.jso file , you can declare the key **AppSetting_Key1_Value** with the value of your Bing maps query key.

**Specify the Parameter Value**

After the Parameter has been added to the ARM Template and it’s being used to populate an Application Setting, the final step is to define the Parameter value within the ARM Templates Parameter file used for deployments. In the Azure Resource Group project template in Visual Studio the Parameters file for the default deployment is the file that ends with “.parameters.json”.
Here’s a screenshot of the “WebSite.parameters.json” file created in the previous articles in this series with the “AppSetting_Key1_Value” Parameter set to a value:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "hostingPlanName": {
        "value": "WebApp1HostingPlan"
      },
      "WebApplication1PackageFolder": {
        "value": "WebApplication1"
      },
      "WebApplication1PackageFileName": {
        "value": "package.zip"
      },
      "WebApp_ConnString1": {
        "value": "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      },
      "AppSetting_Key1_Value": {
        "value":  "Template Value 1"
      }
    }
}
```

for security complaint solution , you can move all your secure key and connection string to Azure key vault if you are not comfortable to have keys in param file.

This should work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! That would be a way to do it, if I already deployed my Maps API. However this pipeline is deploying the whole infrastructure and the environment from scratch. Meaning my Web App and its settings are dependent on the BingMaps resource being deployed first. Updated my question.